# Paste special issue, From Excel to Word

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have an Excel 2013 document that contains many data in many tables. I also have a Word 2013 document that contains empty table shells. What I'd like to do is link the Word document to the Excel document so that the Word document updates when the Excel document is overwritten with new data.

The problem I'm having is that when I highlight multiple cells in Excel, and then highlight the same number of cells in Word, and then paste special in the data, ALL of the cells from Excel get pasted into the upper left cell in Word. Strangely, this hasn't been a problem with normal pasting. Only the special pasting.

I can special paste one cell at a time, but in my case that's thousands of cells and not worth my time if there's a better way. So, is there a way to paste special multiple cells from Excel into a multiple cells in a Word table?

Thanks for the help!
[STEP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKRQI.jpg)

Comment: I believe you are mixing two things: first you mention you want to link your Word file to an Excel file. Then you say that you want to paste your Excel file into your Word file. Both are different: when you paste your excel file, then you create a copy so it won't be linked. I would advise you to search on how to create a link and forget about copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Because the table in the word document is empty, maybe you can try to copy the entire table in excel, and then directly overwrite the table in the word document (or delete the word table first, and then do a special paste)

Comment: I had try to prefill some data in word table first, same issue ;
I need to keep the original table in word file , so any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me presented as image.[Step by step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCzla.jpg)

Comment: While this link you answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.